# How to call a function of child component when the child component is created dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I just wanna call test() function on click of save button. I have used the following code but it's not working, in fact, throwing an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">      
        class NewCandidate extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);               
            }           
            test(){
                alert("Within newCandidate");
            }   

            render(){
                return(
                  <div>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th colSpan="2">Candidate details</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th><td><input type="text" /></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email</th><td><input type="text" ref="candEmail" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" />Male 
                                <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender"  />Female
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                )
            }
        }
        class Interview extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    candidates: [],
                    candidate_name: [],
                    candidate_email: [],
                    interviewer_name: '',
                    phase: ''
                }
                this.addNewCandidate = this.addNewCandidate.bind(this);             
            }           
            addNewCandidate(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var arr=this.state.candidate_name;
                arr.push(null);         
                var arr_email=this.state.candidate_email;
                arr_email.push(null);           
                const candidateList = [].concat(this.state.candidates);
                candidateList.push(<div key={`candidate-${candidateList.length}`}><NewCandidate indexVal={candidateList.length} handleCandidateChangeName={this.handleCandidateChangeName} handleCandidateChangeEmail={this.handleCandidateChangeEmail} handleCandidateChangeGender={this.handleCandidateChangeGender} ref="child" /></div>)
                this.setState({candidates: candidateList});
            }               
            render() {
                return (
                  <div>                 
                    {this.state.candidates}             
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewCandidate} >Add New Candidate</button>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.refs.child.refs.test}>Save</button>             
                  </div>
                )
              }
        }
        // render Interview component
        ReactDOM.render(<Interview />,document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was going through your code trying to understand your question. I find that you are keeping components inside state, which may not be good practice. Keep only your data in state and have the components inside render.

Comment: did you try `onClick={this.refs.child.test}`??

Comment: yes thowring error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: in fact I have posted the code with same thing

Comment: No you are using extra refs in middle. this is what you have posted `this.refs.child.refs.test` ---> change this to `this.refs.child.test`

Comment: but the same thing I have already tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157369/discussion-between-narasimha-reddy-and-abhayjeet-singh).